# Get all client headers in FastCGI (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, http, fastcgi

currently I am struggeling with a little problem:
I want create FastCGI/CGI binding for the [nekoVM](http://nekovm.org). This is done by writing some clue C/C++ code that is loaded by the VM. I want to make the behaviour of my binding as compatible as possible with neko native API (mod_neko, mod_tora). With mod_neko it is possible to get all HTTP headers the client send.
As far as I know you can get HTTP headers with FastCGI only by calling `getenv('header_name')`. To use this function you need to know the name of all headers.

My question: Is there any possibility to get all headers the client send?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the externally-defined, null-terminated `environ` variable on most systems to get an array of all environment variables, which you could iterate to grab the headers you need (assuming FastCGI sets up the environment variables in a sensible way):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    extern char **environ;
    for (int i = 0; environ[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", environ[i]);
    }
}
```

See [man 7 environ](http://linux.die.net/man/7/environ).

Answer (score 4):

Apache's mod_fcgi puts all client http headers in the "FCGX_ParamArray" that you passed into FCGX_Accept (the main loop of the server app). That type is just a char**, with the common pattern "name, value, name, ..." for the strings. So, you just need a loop like this to get them all:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>  hdrs; 
std::string  name = 0;
char*        val  = 0;
int          i;

// "envp" is the FCGX_ParamArray you passed into FCGX_Accept(...) 
for(i=0; envp[i] != NULL; i+=2) {      
    name = envp[i];                    
    val  = envp[i+1];                                
    if(val != NULL) {                  
        hdrs[name] = string(val);      
    } 
    else {
        hdrs[name] = "";
    }                             
}
```

If you're using Apache and want to access all the static config ("httpd.conf") settings as well, they're passed in the "arge" environment block of main().

```
int main(int argc, char** argv, char** arge) {
    ....
}
```

Be aware that not all clients will send all possible headers- CURL, for example, does not send an "accept" header.

Comment: Beware that "Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]." (see [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2)). Thus you should use [std::unordered_multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap), as [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) keys are unique.