# Getting IP of post client

Tags: c, freebsd, fastcgi

Well I know that I should have tried a lot before asking here, but my problem is. It's hard to get structured reference of fcgi documentation. So i hope you won't downvote me that much, even in aspect of little lack of self study.

I'm trying to find a way to archive the IP of the requesting client.

As I guess (if I understood right) I could request the HTTP header of the connection by the FCGX_stream handle. But I would prefer a easier way if there is one.

My first try was checking it about the `getenv` as provided in the first fcgi tutorial, but as I tryed it as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4107212/2003898

It compiled fine, but on first request my fcgi app just crashed. (but it wouldn't solve my problem anyway as I figured out the get env is just requesting MY, so the host ones, env's)

I were also trying arround with the

```
*FCGX_GetParam(const char *name, FCGX_ParamArray envp);
```

function. But either I'm to stupid to use or it is also just providing my local evniroment and not the POST side's one.

So if anyone could tell me how to acces those data (prefered without extracting from HTTP header) or how to use `FCGX_GetParam` to acces it,
I would be thankfull.

**EDIT:**

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{       
    int count = 0;
    while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0)
    {
        for (count = 0; environ[count] != NULL; count++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", environ[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Getting it from the `REMOTE_ADDR` environment variable is what I would have suggested. Perhaps you could show the code you had which accesses the environment and we can figure out why it crashed? It should be straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")`

The remote IP address isn't included in the HTTP headers anyway

Comment: hm and this is the "clients" IP addres, not mine? I thought it is the IP address, of my machine. but as I have to say... I was so stupid running it from the same amchine to test ....

Comment: @Zaibis yes it's the client's IP. That's what the "REMOTE" means. :)

Comment: ah ok... ehm... is there also such a simple way of getting the url the remote side has runned the post on?

Comment: In most cases, you can use `getenv("HTTP_REFERER")` to get the URL of the page that contained the form, but you shouldn't rely on this information being correct (it may not be available at all). A better solution is to include a hidden identifier field in the form itself.

Comment: Hmm both sounds nice. awesome :) but what are cases where it couldn't be availabe? as I just want to make a login verification, and as if the url wouldn't contain the login code I generated to the IP he jsut had to login again. Or are there also ways where it could contain wrong informations, even if the user doesn't try to hack my programm? because if the user want's to harm the worst case just would be he ahd to login again.

Comment: `getenv (HTTP_REFERER);` makes my fcgi app crash :/ I got to add: the URL the client is accessing doesn't exist in any directory hierachy, as it is randomly generated. If i enter a page with a directory that exists, the app doesn't crash.

Comment: Almost all standard browsers send the `Referer` header by default, but it's not absolutely essential according to the HTTP standard. Some browsers allow users to disable this header altogether. It's also quite easy to fabricate HTTP requests containing fake header information. For a login form, your best option is to put a randomized session token inside a hidden field so you can be sure that the user submitted a genuine form. Don't forget the double quotation marks in `getenv ("HTTP_REFERER")`. The function will return `NULL` if this environment variable is not set.

Comment: Ofc I didn't forgot the quotation marks. The code compiles, it crashes on runtime. I got a main index page which is jsut autoredirecting to www.myurl.com/test then all is fine and i get displayed as HTTPrefferer "www.myurl.com". But if I enter www.myurl.com/test manually (thats where my fcgi loop hooks up), then the fcgi event loop just quites. and for a radomized session token, I would need java scripts, wouldnt I?

Comment: Like I said, the `Referer` header isn't always set (see [rfc2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.36)). Your code crashes because you're dereferencing a null pointer.